# What is the best collation when using JSON and some special characters

Tags: php, mysql, json, collation

I'm trying to get data from mysql database with php and JSON and it's not working because of the collation I've chosen.
I'm using these characters  : ® ,é, è , ™, É
My deafult collation in mysql is: latin1_swedish_ci,and my server default collation is: utf8mb4_unicode_ci. 
Should I just remove those special characters or what? 
this the php code:

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";
$sql = "select * from produit";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // result contient tous les produits 
$response = array(); // on déclare un array
// pour chaque ligne de la table 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
array_push($response, array("id_produit"=>$row[0] , "nom"=>$row[1], "catégorie"=>$row[2], "description"=>$row[3], "type"=>$row[4], "prix"=>$row[5], "qte_stock"=>$row[6]));
}
echo json_encode(array("server_response"=> $response));
mysqli_close($conn);

 ?>
```

show create table produit :

```
CREATE TABLE `produit` (
 `id_produit` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nom` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `catégorie` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
 `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `prix` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `qte_stock` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_produit`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

Comment: I use utf8_bin with french characters. Also, see if you can set UTF characters with the function `mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");`.

Comment: i think you need to use html unicode utf-8 value (https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp) and change db/table Collation is utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: thank you, but it's not working

Comment: thank you @Jayanta I'll try what you've suggested

Comment: You should `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` before you encounter characters that cannot be converted to latin1.

Comment: I tried that but believe me it doesn't work

Comment: Best way for JSON field : encoding *utf8mb4* and collation *utf8mb4_bin* (that now default in MySQL 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all those wondering how to solve the problem with french characters and JSON trust me I've tried everything these days the only thing that works is :

```
echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

here's the link for more information http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php thank god for that, I lost hope for a second

Comment: Yes, that generates UTF-8 byte sequences.  In MySQL such is called `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  You mentioned `utf8`.  It might work, but it is missing Emoji and some Chinese characters.

Comment: @r Thank you for the advice  but

Comment: @RickJames Thank you for the advice  but it's my hopeless solution, I don't have any other choice, by the way I read one of your answers and I  was amazed by your experience I was realy hoping that you could answer me, do you have any other solutions instead of mine please?

Comment: Please provide the code that includes `mysqli_set_charset`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and anything else relevant.  There are several places where one must specify utf8 in some fashion; missing any one leads to disaster.  There is not quite enough info for me to point you to a specific part of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .

Comment: @RickJames That's the answer I saw before which helped me change many things in my database, I edited my question it contains now the create table code, and for mysqli_set_charset I tried to use it but it always gives errors so I removed it

Comment: Well, you really need to do `SET NAMES` in some way.  You seem to be using `mysqli_*`, so I am surprised that charset failed.  Do you have more details?

Comment: I'm wondering if I have to set something before importing the database to the web host, I think I'm missing something @RickJames

Comment: How are you doing the "import"?

Comment: @RickJames I use the character set of the file as "utf-8" and Ieave all the other options at their default values

Comment: "utf-8" is valid _outside_ mysql.  Inside, you need "utf8" or "utf8mb4".  Are you using `LOAD DATA`?  Or some other mechanism to "import"?

Comment: @RickJames I'm just a beginner, this is the first time I use Mysql, I used to work with oracle, anyway so if you mean by LOAD DATA  browsing the computer and selecting a file then Yes. also I descovered that the default import comments all this part: '/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;'

Comment: [_This_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) is what I meant.

Comment: No that's not what I used, anyway I think that reading one or two answers won't be enough I have many many things to learn, so if you can suggest me some good references I'll be greatful, and thank you so much for everything @RickJames